# Why model.find() in mongoose is running before creating the collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this task for creating a database with mongoose and do some CRUD operations:
First I created my server.js file for creating a server and connecting a database to the server
My problem is when I run my app for the first time the person.find() result is always empty!!

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const personRoute = require('./routes/personRoute')

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

//Connecting the database to the server 
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:123456@checkpoint.scbz2.mongodb.net/Checkpoint?retryWrites=true&w=majority', 
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useCreateIndex: true
    },
    err => {
        if(err) throw err
        else console.log('Database is connected')
    }
);

//Using routes with express Router
app.use(personRoute)

//Creating server on port 5000
app.listen(5000 , err => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else console.log('Server is running on port 5000')
})
```

personSchema.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

//Creating a person schema
const personSchema = new Schema({
    name : {type : String, required : true},
    age : Number,
    favoriteFood : [String]
});

//Exporting the person schema
const person = mongoose.model('person', personSchema);
module.exports = person;
```

personRoute:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
const person = require('../model/personSchema');
let arrayOfPeople = require('../arrayOfPeople');
//
let exemple = new person({
    name : "Mohamed", age : 26, favoriteFood : ['pasta', 'mloukhia', 'jelbena']
});
exemple.save((err,exemple) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    else console.log('exemple created and saved: ', exemple);
});
//
person.create(arrayOfPeople,(err, data) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    else console.log('collection created :', data)
})
//
person.find({name : "Mohamed"}, (err, document) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    else console.log('Find person by name :', document)
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is in personRoute.js because when I run my app I always get the person.find() result empty actually it always runs before saving the exemple/creating the collection here's an image of my problem:

[Image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf3JX.png)

Any help will be always appreciated :)

Comment: This is hoy asynchronus code works. Try using `await` or place `find` method inside `save()` callback.

Comment: What kind of route is this?